# Error while login in Admin Dashboard (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I want to create a login form for admin dashboard. I have already created the relevant Controllers and blades but when I try login in admin dashboard error of EloquentUserProvider. I only want a login form for admin side not for users.

**Error:**

> FatalThrowableError in EloquentUserProvider.php line 114:
>       Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\Admin given, called in
>   C:\Ampps\www\jobapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php
>   on line 385

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/admin/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/', 'Admin\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/admin/logout', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@adminlogout')->name('admin.logout');
```

Comment: use a middle ware to block common users

Comment: where and how ??

Comment: Write a middleware in App/Http/Middleware to check  access, then call it in controller method or in construct

Comment: Read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware, and edit the middleware according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

if you want login, register, reset password, dashboard

cd your current directory

then type below command you will get login, register, reset password, dashboard

```
**php artisan make:auth**
```